# Ignoring undefined values in object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I made a function in Javascript (Node.js) that saves data to a database. I'm passing an object with different datafields, but it's not certain the object has every data field that the function uses defined.

```
   var obj = {value1: '1', value2: '2'}

   function(obj) {

            mongooseDoc = new Doc({
                    value1: obj.value1,
                    value2: obj.value2,
                    value3: obj.value3,
                    value4: obj.value4,
                    value5: obj.value5.value6
            }

   }
```

This will give an error because obj.value3 - 6 is undefined. How do you code this so it won't give an error without having to use 3 if statements? Would you have to declare the whole object with all possible values first or is there a cleaner method?

**UPDATE: How could you handle this for value6, when value5 is undefined in this case? **

Comment: Couldn't you create a function that removes all the keys that map to undefined?

Comment: Why can't you use `mongooseDoc = new Doc(obj);`?  What is the purpose of creating that new object?

Comment: @SuperScript For the sake of clarity I simplified the example, the new Doc(obj) uses data from other objects too.

Comment: Do you have underscore/lodash or any other utilities in your app?

Comment: @megawac yes underscore and async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
**[JSFIDDLE  DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/cQ9Vs/1/)**

```
var obj = {value1: '1', value2: '2'};

   function hello(obj) {

            var Doc = {
                    value1: obj.value1 || "",
                    value2: obj.value2 || "",
                    value3: obj.value3 || "",
                    value4: obj.value4 || "",
                    value5: obj.value5 || ""
            };
       console.log(Doc);
       alert(Doc);

   }

hello(obj);
```

**Would recommend to use [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org) Great JS Library to work with**

**UPDATE with Underscore**

```
var obj = {value1: '1', value2: '2'};

   function hello(obj) {

            var mongooseDoc =  _.clone(obj);
            console.log(mongooseDoc);
            alert("Please See in Console:" + mongooseDoc);

   }
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/cQ9Vs/2/)**

**Another Update for multiple objects:**

```
var obj1 = {value1: '1', value2: '2'};
var obj2 = {value3: '3', value4: '4'};

   function hello(obj1,obj2) {

            var mongooseDoc =  _.extend(_.clone(obj1),_.clone(obj2)); //list goes here
            console.log(mongooseDoc);
            alert("Please See in Console:" + mongooseDoc);

   }

hello(obj1,obj2);
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/cQ9Vs/3/)**

Comment: if the field/property names are changing, I don't see how the underscore solutions would help?

Comment: we can bind `change` callback whenever there is a change in any object and will trigger the `hello(...)` function. That way the updated obj1, obj2,... will be cloned to the variable. I have just mentioned how to solve the OP's problem, there are many decent ways to deal with underscore and backbone together to play with data and views.

Comment: Your first answer works, while the others don't. The question wasn't about backbone. In fact, it was about Mongoose, which has it's own particular requirements.

Comment: May be, but the OP doesn't specify it particularly for the mongoose (and sorry, I'm unaware of that). Never mind, the OP's problem is solved and I even give him the insight to use `underscore.js` as he specify that he's using it. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use it like this:

```
function(obj) {

        mongooseDoc = new Doc({
                value1: obj.value1,
                value2: obj.value2,
                value3: obj.value3 || "",
                value4: obj.value4 || "",
                value5: obj.value5 || ""
        });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

situation with value5.value6 can be handled like this:

```
function getProperty(obj, path, defaultValue) {
    return path.split('.').reduce(function(obj, x) { return (obj != null) ? obj[x] : undefined; }, obj) || defaultValue;
}
alert(getProperty(obj, 'value5.value5', '123');
```